# How to create a python package in PyCharm using __init__.py files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import, pycharm

I created a simple project with a package using Python and Tkinter in PyCharm. The project file structure is:

```
project
|_ package
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ main.py
   |_ widgets  (a dir)
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ widget_a.py
      |_ widget_b.py
```

File `project/package/__init__.py` contains the below to minimize the number of times `tkinter` and `ttk` are to be imported.:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
```

File `project/package/main.py` contains a `Tk` root window with `WidgetA` (i.e. a `ttk.Frame`) and `WidgetB` (i.e. a `ttk.Button`). See below:

```
from package import *
from package.widgets import *


class App(WidgetA):
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.button = WidgetB(self, text=text)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)

       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root, "MyButton")
    app.grid(row=0, column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

File `project/package/widgets/__init__.py` contains:

```
from .. import *
from .widget_a import *
from .widget_b import *
```

File `project/package/widgets/widget_a.py` contains class `WidgetA` which itself is a `ttk.Frame`:

```
from . import *

__all__ = ["WidgetA"]


class WidgetA(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
```

File `project/package/widgets/widget_b.py` contains class `WidgetB` which itself is a `ttk.Button`:

```
from . import *

__all__ = ["WidgetB"]


class WidgetB(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        super().__init__(master, text=text)
```

The above codes work as PyCharm creates a GUI that looks like this:

[image: GUI]

However, these same scripts don't seem to work in PyCharm when I make a new project where the project and package folders are made at the same level, i.e. its file structure becomes

```
package
|_ __init__.py
|_ main.py
|_ widgets  (a dir)
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ widget_a.py
   |_ widget_b.py
```

Error msg:

```
File "~/package/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

When the `package` syntax in line 1 is replaced with `.`, the following error message is issued:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/package/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Can you help me understand the above-mentioned issues?

Comment: For your first example, `main.py` should be inside `project` folder, otherwise it is basically the same as the second example and same error will be raised.